# Teradata Rounding Error, Set Operations

Tags: sql, decimal, union, teradata

We're testing for difference between two sets and seeing some counterintuitive behavior for rounding in UNION/MINUS operations.  What is the explanation for this?

If you evaluate only the first line of the Union statement (Source - Target), you get one mismatch. This is correct.- there is a .000005 difference.

However, if you evaluate only the second line, you get no records returned. This means that Teradata evaluates these two numbers as equivalent when we are doing Target-Source.

Further, when the entire Union statement is run, you get 2 mismatches! So it does recognize that Target-Source is different as well.

How can 1+0 = 2? i.e. Shouldn't the cardinality of the union between two sets be the sum of the cardinalities (ignoring duplicates.)

There is also another example attached.

---

example described:

```
   WITH SOURCE_RESULT(TEST) AS (
   SELECT cast(.0296250 as decimal(10,7))
   ),
   TARGET_RESULT(TEST) AS (
   SELECT cast(.02962 as decimal(10,5))
   )

  ((SELECT * FROM SOURCE_RESULT) MINUS (SELECT * FROM TARGET_RESULT))
  UNION 
  ((SELECT * FROM TARGET_RESULT) MINUS (SELECT * FROM SOURCE_RESULT));
```

---

example 2:

```
   WITH SOURCE_RESULT(TEST) AS (
   SELECT cast(.0843090 as decimal(10,7))
   ),
   TARGET_RESULT(TEST) AS (
   SELECT cast(.08431 as decimal(10,5))
   )

   ((SELECT * FROM SOURCE_RESULT) MINUS (SELECT * FROM TARGET_RESULT))
   UNION 
   ((SELECT * FROM TARGET_RESULT) MINUS (SELECT * FROM SOURCE_RESULT));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the odd behavior you see here can be attributed to the order of operations in field casting that Teradata does in order to perform the set operations.

With `MINUS` Teradata uses the Decimal precision of the first set, so in the case of:

```
source MINUS target
```

Both `source` and `target` are changed to have a precision of 7 and then the `MINUS` set operation occurs.

When we do:

```
target MINUS source
```

Both are changed to a precision of 5, which results in two identical numbers, so we get an empty result set

So far this is pretty expected behavior.

When we complicate it by adding in a UNION, then the Decimal precision of the result set (and calculations used to create it) are determined by the top-left query, so:

```
source MINUS target
UNION
target MINUS source
```

Results in all 4 initial fields changed to a Decimal precision of 7. Then the two `MINUS` set comparisons occur, then finally the `UNION`. The result is that the bottom `MINUS` is now comparing with a precision 7 Decimal and that .000005 difference now affects the results.

As an experiment you can invert the `UNION` in one of your examples like:

```
 WITH SOURCE_RESULT(TEST) AS (
    SELECT cast(.0843090 as decimal(10,7))
   ),
   TARGET_RESULT(TEST) AS (
    SELECT cast(.08431 as decimal(10,5))
   )

  ((SELECT TARGET_RESULT.* FROM TARGET_RESULT) MINUS (SELECT source_result.* FROM SOURCE_RESULT))
  UNION
  ((SELECT SOURCE_RESULT.* FROM SOURCE_RESULT) MINUS (SELECT TARGET_RESULT.* FROM TARGET_RESULT));
```

Where now we are doing:

```
target MINUS source
UNION
source MINUS target
```

And since everything is rounded to a precision of 5 (The top-left field being a `DECIMAL(10,5)`) you get an empty result set back.

Comment: "The data type, title, and format clauses contained in the first SELECT statement determine the data type, title, and format information that appear in the final result." 

See 




  http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_151K/attributes_of_a_set_result_ATTRIBUTES_SET_RESULT.html

Comment: @dnoeth : Excellent, the first set in a set operation determines the schema. Makes sense. However, its not really rounding is it? It's just lopping off anything past the 5th decimal digit. Other wise the .00005 should round up and make them different.

Comment: Teradata supports two ways of rounding, "round half to even" and "round half away from zero", http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding Your system is set to #1: http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/SQL_Reference/B035_1143_151K/Numeric_Types.031.64.html